# bind parameter supply on stored procedure in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, datagridview

i have stored procedure to display a data from my database. using sql server 2008.  my stored procedure like below

```
USE [RSUPDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spSPDMonStockProductHarian]    Script Date: 07/11/2013 14:56:53 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSPDMonStockProductHarian]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Tanggal    Smalldatetime,
    @WHSID      Int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT  NoReff, ProductID,Qnty , CreatedBy, CreatedDate, 
                      LastUpdatedBy, LastUpdatedDate, Computer, ComputerDate
FROM         tblSPDTrnHasilProduksiDtl
Where CreatedDate=@Tanggal 

END
```

I call that stored procedure using vb.net like below

```vb
Private Sub CmRefresh_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmRefresh.Click
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim strCon1 As String = "server='ip server'; database=database name; user=user;password=password;"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("spSPDMonStockProductHarian", New SqlConnection(strCon1))
    'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblSPDTrnHasilProduksiDtl"
    With cmd

        .Parameters.Add("@Tanggal", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = Format(CDate(DateTimePicker1.Value), "dd/MM/yyyy")
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhsID", CboWhs.SelectedValue)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoReff", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Listdata.Rows(i).Cells(0).FormattedValue.ToString
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Listdata.Rows(i).Cells(1).FormattedValue.ToString
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qnty", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Listdata.Rows(i).Cells(2).FormattedValue.ToString
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Listdata.Rows(i).Cells(3).FormattedValue.ToString
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Listdata.Rows(i).Cells(4).FormattedValue.ToString
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdatedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Listdata.Rows(i).Cells(5).FormattedValue.ToString
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdatedDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Listdata.Rows(i).Cells(6).FormattedValue.ToString
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Computer", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Listdata.Rows(i).Cells(7).FormattedValue.ToString
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Computerdate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Listdata.Rows(i).Cells(8).FormattedValue.ToString
        .Connection.Open()
    End With
    Listdata.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader

    Koneksi.Close()
    Koneksi.Close()
End Sub
```

My problem when I execute this program, still error with message

> Procedure or function 'spSPDMonStockProductHarian' expects parameter '@Tanggal', which was not supplied

i didn't get what the problem??? and this make my head stack so any solution will appreciate!!

Answer (score 1):

It is commented out

```vb
'.Parameters.Add("@Tanggal", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = Format(CDate(DateTimePicker1.Value), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

try to remove the quote at beggining,

Said that, your code will fail for other reasons.

The procedure expected only two parameters not eleven, the `@Tanggal` parameter should be a datatime not a string formatted as a DateTime, you need to set the `CommandType` property as StoredProcedure.

A more correct approach to your procedure could be this

```vb
Private Sub CmRefresh_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmRefresh.Click 
    Dim strCon1 = "server=serverIP; database=database name; user=user;password=password;"
    Dim cmdText = "spSPDMonStockProductHarian"
    Using con = new SqlConnection(strCon1)
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdText, con)
       With cmd
           .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
           .Parameters.Add("@Tanggal", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value
           .Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhsID", CboWhs.SelectedValue)
        End With
         con.Open()
        Listdata.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
    End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I have removed the unused parameters and passed the @Tanggal parameter as a DateTime not as a string. Also added the [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to correctly close and dispose the connection object

Comment: ya my mistake tha quote still there, i think by ignored that message will not appear..can you give an example...

Comment: succes to eliminate the message error but have new problem that data i call nothing display

Comment: Try to call that procedure from Sql Server Management Studio (do you have the time part in field?)

Comment: can you give me to an example, how to call procedure from Sql Server Management Studio??

Comment: Open SSMS, find your database and your Stored Procedure, right click on the name of the SP and Execute, fill the required params and check if you have any returned rows

Comment: i call Stored Procedure in database, as you suggest ,but have message still error  "Procedure or function 'spSPDMonStockProductHarian' expects parameter '@tanggal', which was not supplied." can you give me example